# Integer to string in App Inventor

Tags: android, string, int, app-inventor

I would like to know whether the App Inventor have any "proper" way to convert the integer to string?

**e.g.:** toString() in C++

Currently i am using an indirect way,using "trim" function in the string to convert the integer to string.

Comment: Yes,I did check the issue on App Inventor tutorial,online and Taifun's blog as well.The intention of asking this question is because of I am doing an app that will save the data into a online PHP database,before I used the trim method,the app always get the Error 1101 when I was tring to send the data to database,and the error also prompted without any explanation.So I only can guess it maybe was causing by data type issue or maybe the variable containing "Escape Sequences".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conversion from *integer* to *string* necessary, just use the variable as it is.

Same for *string* to *integer*. In this case you might want to test first, if it is a number using the `is a number` block, see also http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/math.html#isnumber.

[image]

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)

Comment: There is a necessity to this, shame there isn't one implemented.

Comment: ??? sorry, I don't understand, what you are talking about, you might want to elaborate...

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys this is late to the response but I just had this problem while sending data via BLE to a device and App Inventor would not acknowledge that I needed the numbers to be used as a String so I got errors. A simple fix I found after a while was to use the 'join' function in the 'text' options.

Just put join and your integer value on top, and 'join' it with an empty text box.